# why I got the right message from the usart of stm32 when debugged by Keil MDK , but got a wrong out put from USART when using eclipse+CDT

Tags: eclipse, stm32, usart

I install these Plug-in in eclipse to build the stm32 develop environment:
GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-in
CDT GNU Cross Development Tools
Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2014.05-28 for ARM EABI
J-Link ARM V4.15e

I am trying to run a USART1 program in eclipse and check the output of the USART1,but when I debug this code,I got the wrong output message. The message I send is "DECA0130",but what I got is "???????"，this is obviously a garbled.

At first, I think the problem is I didn't write a write code .I checked my project again.But didn't find any error.
Then I build a new project in Keil Mdk use the same code.This time I got the right message from USATR1.I receive the string "DECA0130".

It's very strange. Because I'm not familiar with eclipse environment,I used Keil do my coding before.But the recent projects have forced me to write code .I think maybe somewhere I forgot to configure.
Because it's a new user，I don't know how to insert the program。If there is any need, please tell me.I will try my best to let you see
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a clock issue. Check the clock settings. The eclipse ARM plugin generates some configs for that. Check the function `SetSysClock` in the `system/src/cmsis/system_stm32*.c` file. I think the Keil MDK does this too, but with differnt config.

Edit: The function `SetSysClock` i mentioned is wrong. The clock config is done in the `configure_system_clock` function (file `_initialize_hardware.c`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand what you mean.But I didn't find the configure_system_clock in my project....